# Using properties file for tweepy credentials

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Is it possible to use a properties file in `tweepy` (as in case of `twitter4j`) in order to read the credentials and not hard-code the keys inside the code? If this is possible, can I use several properties files for different credentials?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [ConfigParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html#ConfigParser.RawConfigParser.readfp) in your program to store and load the credentials.